# Magazine Cut Size

Tags: adobe-indesign

I want to design a magazine at the standard magazine size of 8.375 x 10.875. Does that mean I start with an 8.5 x 11 letter size in InDesign for each page? Or do I design in InDesign as 8.375 x 10.875? I'm asking this to printers in town and they can't answer, or I'm not confident they know what I'm talking about. I've read that printers "cut" to the 8.375 x 10.875 size... but what dimension of a page do you send to the printer. Does anyone know what I'm talking about? Or have first hand experience with this?

Comment: You ask the printer that will be printing your magazine.

Answer (score 1):

Set up your page size as 8.375x10.875" in InDesign. The document size in InDesign should **match** your final printed piece.

The crop marks indicate the trim when you export to PDF for press. Printers simply trim at the trim marks. You need to be certain your page size matches what you want the final trim size to be.

8.375x10.875" is used so that you can have a bleed and not require oversized stock when printing. This customarily reduces printing costs.

I do this at least once a week, if not more often.